# Do interfaces inherit from Object class in java

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

Do interfaces inherit from `Object` class in Java?

If no then how we are able to call the method of object class on interface instance

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e = null;
        e.equals(null);
    }
}

interface Employee {
}
```

Comment: @EJP, technically speaking it doesn't matter what java/io/Serializable.class contains. I think you're confusing the Java Lang Spec with the JVM spec.

Comment: @aioobe As I haven't mentioned either of those specifications I don't understand your point. `Serializable` is an interface, the simplest possible; running `javap` on it tells you what it inherits from; and that is dictated by the Java Language Specification. If you think the JVM Spec comes into it somewhere please enlighten us.

Comment: @EJP, the question is about the Java language (i.e. the Java Language Specification). What ever java/io/Serializable.class contains is related to what the JVM spec says. Technically speaking there is no guarantee that there is a one-to-one correspondence between features of the two specifications.

Comment: I elaborated on this in a recent [blog post](http://aioo.be/2016/08/24/JLS-vs-JVMS.html).

Answer (score 170):

> ***Do interfaces inherit from `Object` class in Java?***

No, they don't. And there is no common "root" interface implicitly inherited by all interfaces either (as in the case with classes) for that matter.<sup>(*)</sup>

> ***If no then how we are able to call the method of object class on interface instance***

An interface implicitly declared one method for each public method in `Object`. Thus the `equals` method is implicitly declared as a member in an interface (unless it already inherits it from a superinterface).

This is explained in detail in the Java Language Specification, [§ 9.2 Interface Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2).

> #### 9.2 Interface Members
>
> [...]
>
> - If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, **then the interface implicitly declares a public abstract member method *m* with signature *s*, return type *r*, and throws clause *t* corresponding to each public instance method m with signature *s*, return type *r*, and throws clause *t* declared in `Object`**, unless a method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by the interface.
>
> [...]

---

This post has been rewritten as an article [here](http://programming.guide/java/do-interfaces-inherit-from-object.html).

---

<sup>(*) Note that the notion of being a *subtype of* is not equivalent to *inherits from*: Interfaces with no super interface are indeed subtypes of `Object` ([§ 4.10.2. Subtyping among Class and Interface Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2) ) even though they do not inherit from `Object`.</sup>

Comment: Does this explain the behavior of `boolean isObject = myList instanceof Object` being true? Or is that because `instanceof` looks at what the object actually is, not what your reference to it is.

Comment: `instanceof` performs the check against the runtime type (otherwise the whole instanceof-expression could be evaluated at compile time).

Comment: @aioobe If we implement any interface, then why don't we give the implementation of "equals" method in the class which is implementing that interface. According to my concepts,we have to implement the methods of interface in implementing class otherwise the class will be abstract.

Comment: You don't need to (re)implement inherited methods. Have a look at [this example](http://pastebin.com/p1z6NBUx). In other words, equals is already defined and inherited to the class implementing the interface.

Comment: After reading this answer, it makes more sense to see `class Object` as `class Root` in java.

Comment: I got the point here. But one question- why do we need this? What difference it would have made if the methods of `Object` class would not have been declared in the interface ?

Comment: If we didn't have this, the program in the question would not compile. There is on `equals` method in the `Employee` interface.

Comment: below Oracle link states that, "Reference types all inherit from java.lang.Object. Classes, enums, arrays, and interfaces are all reference types." This is contradicting. Can someone throw light on it ? [Lesson: Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/index.html) @aioobe

Comment: This question and answer still reminds me that even after experience i should focus on making my basics strong.

Comment: What happens in the following case : Class Dummy extends Test implements Employee {...} . Dummy would have two methods with same signature (one defined in Object class and the other declared in interface 
Employee) ?

Comment: @prvn, that's not a problem since there's still just one *implementation* of the method.

Comment: Why do interfaces need this special treatment? Wouldn't it have been simpler to inherit from Object like everything else?

Answer (score 20):

`Object` is a supertype of any interface [1]

However, an interface does not `implements`, `extends`, or, *"inherit from"* `Object`.

JLS has a special clause to add `Object` methods into interfaces [2]

[1] http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10.2

[2] http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.2

Comment: That's the most accurate answer. Should be the accepted one. E.g. a method which takes a ```java.lang.Object``` will also accept a reference of any interface type. Moreover you can cast interface to an ```Object``` implicitly without any compiler error.

Answer (score 12):

There is actually a superclass field in every `.class` file, including those that represent interfaces.

For an interface it always points to `java.lang.Object`.  But that isn't used for anything.

Another way to look at it is:

```
interface MyInterface {
    // ...
}

public myMethod(MyInterface param) {
    Object obj = (Object) param;
    // ...
}
```

Here the cast `(Object) param` is always valid, which implies that every interface type is a subtype of `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: The .class file is an artifact of the .java file. To argue why something works in Java language by looking at the resulting .class file is backward reasoning.

Comment: Object obj = (Object) param; does not throw compilation error. But MyInterface's methods (public) are not visible to obj. Therefore can't assume MyInterface is every interface type is a subtype of java.lang.Object

Answer (score 5):

That's because `employee e = ...` reads that there is a class that **implements** `employee`, and is assigned to variable `e`. Every class that implements an interface extends Object implicitly, hence when you do `e.equals(null)`, the language knows that you have a class that is a subtype of `employee`.

The JVM will do runtime checking for your code (i.e. throw `NullPointerException`).

Answer (score 3):

**Is interface inherits Object class, how can we able to access the methods of object class through a interface type reference**
No Interface does not inherits `Object` class, but it provide accessibility to all methods of `Object` class. 
The members of an interface are:

```
Those members declared in the interface.
Those members inherited from direct superinterfaces.
If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface implicitly
```

**declares a public abstract member method corresponding to each public instance method declared in `Object` class**.
 It is a compile-time error if the interface explicitly declares such a method m in the case where m is declared to be `final` in `Object`.

Now it is clear that all superinterface have `abstract` member method corresponding to each `public` instance method declared in `Object`.

source:
http://ohmjavaclasses.blogspot.com/2011/11/is-intreface-inherits-object-clashow.html

Answer (score 0):

Any class implementing any interface is also derived from `Object` as well by definition.

Answer (score 0):

"**Reference types all inherit from java.lang.Object**. Classes, enums, arrays, and **interfaces are all reference types.**"

Quoted from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/index.html
Second sentence to be clear.

Comment: `Classes, enums, and arrays (which all inherit from java.lang.Object) as well as interfaces are all reference types` : it does not say interface inherits from Object. Only Classes , enums and arrays.

Comment: They changed it :)

Comment: Even if "they changed it" (which I doubt), the tutorial can be wrong. The normative reference is the Java Language Specification (JLS).

Answer (score 0):

An interface does not and cannot extend Object class, because an interface has to have public and abstract methods.

For every public method in the Object class, there is an implicit public and abstract method in an interface.

This is the standard Java Language Specification which states like this,

> “If an interface has no direct super interfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t declared in Object, unless a method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by the interface.”

Answer (score 0):

The method of compiling the inserted object declaration is not found in the class file. The method name of the object for which the metaclass information is not obtained is reflected at runtime. According to the official description, the method signature of the object is implicitly extended, which may be allowed by the JVM runtime mechanism