# How the non final method of object class is visible to interface

Tags: java

I am confused on one scenario of interface.Below is the code in which I haven't declare  the `toString()` method in interface.
It is the method of object class.But still `toString()` method is able to execute from the parent class reference variable .But the rule says that before calling the child class method it first look method in interface, if method is present then call the child class method but in this scenario *How `toString()` is executed without declaration in interface* 
please explain me

```
    public interface Parent {
    void show();
}

class Base implements Parent {
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("hey it is going to be execute");
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "itspossible";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent parent = new Base();
        System.out.println(parent.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This works because every class extends the `Object` class implicitly. Therefore any implementation of any interface, has the `toString()` method available.

Answer (score 1):

Its because the `toString` method is included on `Object` which every class is derived from.  The method is being called from the `Object` class.

I found this question answered by Jon Skeet that explains it well:

[Does an interface by default extend Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776018/does-an-interface-by-default-extend-object)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, `parent` is an object reference from `Base` class. Note that all classes extends from `Object` class, thus having the methods defined in `Object` class such as `toString`.

Answer (score 0):

it is because `Object` class is a base class for every class and it includes `toString` method. So when you call `toString` with parent's reference, it'll call parent's `toString().`

Answer (score 0):

The variable `parent` is just a reference which is referring to its subtype `Child`. Here you are creating an object of `Child` which by default extends `Object` class. You are overriding the `toString` method hence giving this output.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `toString` method of interface but it's `Bash`  Class method. Each object have a default implementation of `toString` method even you not explicit implement it.

[How can instance of interface access method of Object class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226792/how-can-instance-of-interface-access-method-of-object-class)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the following [discussion](http://www.coderanch.com/t/376901/java/java/dynamic-binding-interfaces). The Java language works as if there was a super interface that all interfaces, including the one above in your comment, and the `Object` class inherit from, which declares all the methods that the `Object` class implements. Unfortunately, that interface doesn't really exist, the compiler just behaves as if it would exist.