# Casting "with" Interface

Tags: java

```
interface I{}
class A implements I{}
class B{}
```

First:

```
I[] arr = new A[10];
arr[0] = (I) new B(); // will produce ClassCastException at runtime
```

Second:
wherein if I use concrete class

```
I[] arr = new A[10];
arr[0] = (A) new B(); // will produce compile-time error
```

What's the difference if in my first example,`(I) new B()`, the java compiler should produce compile-error as well?

Isn't it that the java compiler should be able to distinguish that it is also an "inconvertible type"? Especially when the new operator comes immediately?

Is there any instance/chance that it will be possible that creating that new instance of B could produce a 
convertible type of type I?

I know at some point, that the Java compiler should not immediately say that it is a compiler error, like when you do this:

```
I i = (I) getContent(); // wherein getContent() will return a type of Object
```

**Edit:**

Let me clarify this question why it is not a possible duplicate of this: [Cast reference of known type to an interface outside of type's hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347252/cast-reference-of-known-type-to-an-interface-outside-of-types-hierarchy)

The intention of this question is not because I am not aware of what will be the result of or what is something wrong with something, etc.

I just want to know a "more detailed explanation in a technical way" of why does the JVM behave that way or why does Java came up with that kind of decision of not making that kind of scenario a *compile-time* error.

As what we all know, it is always better to find "problematic code" at compile-time rather than at run-time.

Another thing, the answer I am looking for was found here on this thread not on those "duplicates?".

Comment: I don't think this is restricted to arrays. The same seems to be the case with `I x = (A) new B();` vs. `I y = (I) new B();` For methods this makes sense, as those could return a subclass of the return type that implements the interface. But can a _constructor_ return a subclass of the class it is constructing?

Comment: 16 upvotes already!!! :) ....can we have a better title now!! ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rules for what casts are compile-time legal only take into account the static types.

When the Java compiler analyzes the expression `(I) new B()`, it sees that the static type of the expression `new B()` is `B`. We can tell that `new B()` can't possibly be an instance of `I`, but the compile-time analysis rules can't tell that the object isn't actually an instance of a subclass of `B` that implements `I`.

Thus, the compiler has to let it through. Depending on how sophisticated the compiler is, it might detect the oddity and issue some sort of warning, but in the same way `1/0` isn't a compile-time error, this can't be a compile-time error.

Comment: Thank you @user2357112. So you are saying that the compiler at compile-time analysis only sees the "static type" of every instance that you want to cast? Even if you use a "new" operator immediately after the cast?

Comment: @KevObispo: Pretty much.

Answer (score 5):

The difference in this situation is obviously that `I` is an interface, which could be implemented. This means, that even though `B` has nothing to do with `I`, there could be a subclass of `B`, that implements the interface `I`. Will illustrate this with an example:

```
interface I{}
class A implements I{}
class B{}
class C extends B implements I{}

I[] arr = new A[10]; // valid, cause A implements I
B b = new C(); // Valid because C is a subclass of B
arr[0] = (I) b; // This won't produce ClassCastException at runtime, because b
                // contains an object at runtime, which implements I
arr[0] = (I) new B(); // This will compile but will result in a ClassCastException
                      // at runtime, cause B does not implement I
```

It's important to distinguish the difference between `static` and `dynamic` types. In this case the static type of the variable `b` is `B`, but it has the dynamic type (the runtime type) `C`, where `new B()` does also have the static type `B`, but the dynamic type is also `B`. And as in some cases a cast from `B` to `I` won't result in exceptions (as in this scenario), the compiler allows such casts but **only to an interface type**.

Now take a look at the following scenario:

```
I[] arr = new A[10];
B b = new C(); // Valid because C is a subclass of B
A a1 = (A) b; // compile time error
A a2 = (A) new B(); // compile time error
```

Is it possible that a subclass of `B` will ever extend `A` and `B` at the same time? The answer is **NO**, cause you are limited to only one super class to extend in Java (where in some other OO languages this is not the case), therefore the compiler forbids it, cause there are no possible scenarios, where this will work.

Comment: Thank you @Ivaylo. This could be the answer as well but since somebody has answered it correctly earlier than you did, I have to give him the credit. You have answered it in a very detailed manner indeed. Thank you for that, I appreciate the explanation wherein you specified the difference between the `static` and `dynamic` type. Its just that I didn't realize in the first place that it also applies whenever you do a cast.

Comment: @KevObispo No, you don't have to give mark the first correct answer as accepted - you should use this for the best answer, independent of when the answer appeared. It's often considered a good idea not to mark *any* answer as accepted for 24 hours or so to see what appears.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast any object to the desired var, only if you cast it to the var type:

```
interface I{}
class A implements I{}
class B{}

I var = (I) object; // This is always possible in compile-time, no matter the object type, because object is casted to the var type, I
I var = (A) object; // Not possible in compile-time because of the difference of types
```

The runtime exception comes when the object cannot be casted, but you can't know it until runtime.

```
A object = new A();
I var = (I) object;
B anotherObject = new B();
var = (I) anotherObject;
```

Both of the above will work in compile-time, but only the first one will do it in runtime, because of the implementation of the I interface.

Comment: Yes, I did it, and it works in the way I said

Comment: None of this created a compile time error for me.

Comment: I guess you've actually said that, but you also say in a comment "Not possible in compile-time because of the difference of types"

Answer (score 0):

Class inheritance is single inheritance, no future descendant can introduce a new base class, e.g. in your example, no descendent of `B` can ever be cast to `A`. But it can introduce a new interface, i.e. a descendent of `B` could support `I`.

It's a failing of the compiler that it can't solve your simple case, but it's not a case you would ever see in the wild. Create and cast in one line that is.

**Example of why the compiler can't detect this in a more complex case using your classes**

```
void method(B b){
  I i = (I) b;
}

class C extends B implements I{} // a descendent of B that introduces support for I

method(new A()); //still compile time error
method(new B()); //runtime exception
method(new C()); //works
```

Comment: Thank you Weston, but it's gonna be another story when using a method before you cast. This is just like what I was saying in my last sentence of my question.

Comment: In what case you ever need to cast straight after creation? The java compiler writers haven't catered for this because it's never necessary.

Comment: The method was just to show that I'm casting to a `B` as an interim step. And so for some `B`s it can work at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I tried four cases:

1. Casting a class to another class.
2. Casting a class to an interface.
3. Casting an interface to a class.
4. Casting an interface to another interface.

Compile-time error only happens in the first case.

```
static interface I {}
static interface J {}

static class A {}
static class B {}

Object o = (B) new A();       // compile-time error
Object o = (I) new A();       // runtime error
Object o = (B) ((I) new A()); // runtime error
Object o = (J) ((I) new A()); // runtime error
```

My guess is that this happens because determining whether the cast will succeed or not relatively easier in the first case, compared to the other three cases. The main reason is that a class can only extend one class, which allows the compiler to reason whether the cast will succeed or not. See these examples:

Suppose, in addition to the above classes and interfaces, I add new class:

```
static class C extends B implements I, J {}
```

Example of code that casts a class to an interface (last line):

```
C c = new C();
B b = (B) c;
I i = (I) b; // This is ok.
```

Example of code that casts an interface to a class (last line):

```
C c = new C();
I i = (I) c;
B b = (B) i; // This is ok.
```

Example of code that casts an interface to another interface (last line):

```
C c = new C();
I i = (I) c;
J j = (J) i; // This is ok.
```