# difference between criteria.add and criteria.equals

Tags: hibernate

what is difference between **criteria.add** and **criteria.equals** in hiberante criteria?

just example:

returns 25 records

```
criteria.equals(Restrictions.eq("templateType", TemplateType.DEFAULT_TEMPLATE));
```

returns 2 records:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("templateType", TemplateType.DEFAULT_TEMPLATE));
```

when I do `hibernate.show_sql`, then output is

- for `criteria.equals`, no syntax generated
- for `criteria.add` , this_.template_type=?

Note: Using Hibernate 3.

**Edit:**

```
try{
List<Form> forms=Collections.emptyList();
Criteria normCriteria=session.createCriteria(NormMaster.class);
normCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id",normId));
normCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("libraryId"));
List<Long> libNormIds=normCriteria.list();

if(libNormIds!=null && libNormIds.size()>0)
{
    Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Form.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.in("normId", libNormIds));
    criteria.equals(Restrictions.eq("templateType", TemplateType.DEFAULT_TEMPLATE));
    //criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("templateType", TemplateType.DEFAULT_TEMPLATE));
    criteria.setFetchMode("formControlMaps", FetchMode.JOIN);
    criteria.setFetchMode("formControlMaps.data", FetchMode.JOIN);
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    forms=criteria.list();
}
return forms;
}
 catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code in details?

Comment: There is no `Criteria.equals()`. Are you sure you're not just calling `Object.equals()`?

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman see added more code in question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056124/do-interfaces-inherit-from-object-class-in-java

Comment: @Bhumika, you can see my answer, I've just edited for more clarification of my statement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to compare `criteria.add` with `criteria.equals`.

`criteria.add` adds [Criterion](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion.html) to your [Criteria](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/impl/CriteriaImpl.html), like your case bellow:

```
 criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("templateType", TemplateType.DEFAULT_TEMPLATE));
```

Here `Restrictions.eq("templateType", TemplateType.DEFAULT_TEMPLATE)` returns a `Criterion` object, that is added in your `Criteria` object.

`criteria.equals` is an inherited method from the `Object` class and used for checking equality of java objects! So your code bellow,

```
 criteria.equals(Restrictions.eq("templateType", TemplateType.DEFAULT_TEMPLATE));
```

will do nothing to your `Criteria` object, but only returns `false`. You can be over sure of my statement by simply commenting out the `criteria.equals` code portion.

You will see that this line has no effect in generating your query!

Answer (score 0):

`criteria.equals`: is actually the object equals method which checks whether the passed object is equal to the LHS

`criteria.add`: Adds the passed parameter to the criterias where clause

Answer (score 0):

Adding More to Sazzadur's answer. Criteria interface is implemented by CriteriaImpl and other classes that extends Object class. So criteria.equals invoke Object class's equals method. Ad this is not part of query generation so you not see anything in query generated by hibernate for your criteria.

Hope this helps.