# JAVA: are the notion of subtyping and of inheritance the same thing?

Tags: java, inheritance, subtyping

Based on the note at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6227003/3073460) it looks like subtyping and inheritance are subtly different concepts in Java. What is it? Is inheritance only when a class declaration contains an `extends ...` clause? If this is the case then a class will not inherit from Object, even if it is a subtype of it, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inheritance is a way to achieve subtyping. Taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping):

> In programming language theory, subtyping (also subtype polymorphism or inclusion polymorphism) is a form of type polymorphism in which a subtype is a datatype that is related to another datatype (the supertype) by some notion of substitutability, meaning that program elements, typically subroutines or functions, written to operate on elements of the supertype can also operate on elements of the subtype.

In short, let's look at this:

```
class Super {
}

class Child extends Super {
}
```

This is inheritance, because `Child` inherits everything from `Super`.

```
Super super = new Child();
```

This is subtyping, because we are *referring* to `Child` as a `Super`. So you should see what I mean when I say that Inheritance allows you to perform subtyping, but they are not the same thing.

For example, you can achieve subtyping with interfaces:

```
class Child extends Super implements ISomeInterface {
}
```

Now we can refer to `Child` as:

```
ISomeInterface someInterface = new Child();
```

Here, we're referring to it as the type `ISomeInterface`, without the need for an inheritance relationship.

**Your Questions**

All `Objects` in Java are subclasses of type `Object`. They *implicitly* have `extends Object` in their class header. It's just the way the language works. So yes, every object is a subtype of class `Object`.

In Java, inheritance is only available through the use of the `extends` keyword.

**Extra Reading**

- The [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) is a design principle that heavily focuses on the idea of subtyping
- [The different relationships](http://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/CompoInherit1.html) between Java classes. This will help you gain a deeper understanding of OOP.

**Edit**

Listen to everything Marko Topolnik says. He is pretty smart you know.

Comment: Are you suggesting that `Child` dos not inherit form `ISomeInterface`? What exactly items does it not inherit?

Comment: It doesn't inherit anything from the interface. The class *realises* the interface.

Comment: What, in particular, does it not inherit? In fact, try to disprove this statement: the class inherits *everything there is to inherit* from an interface.

Comment: But there is nothing to inherit. Inheritance is by definition the acquisition of functionality and variables from a superclass, by a subclass. This is a contract, where the concrete implementation provides functionality for the interface.

Comment: There is something to inherit, and quite a lot in fact since Java 8: 1. static constants; 2. default methods; 3. static methods. Of these, only 3. is not inherited.

Comment: Anyway, if there was nothing to inherit, and nothing was inherited, then *everything there is to inherit* was inherited. You cannot decide which way of looking is correct, so there is no essence in claiming that an interface is special in that way. For comparison, if I extend `abstract class X { abstract int method(); }`, have I inherited from it on not, according to your implied criterion?

Comment: I'm not completely following you, but this sounds like one of those conversations where I'm behind. I'll add an edit.

Answer (score 5):

The footnote reads:

> As it happens the notion of *"subtype"* is not entirely in line with *"inherits from"*: Interfaces with no super interface are indeed subtypes of `Object` ([§ 4.10.2. Subtyping among Class and Interface Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2) ) even though they do not inherit from `Object`.

Interfaces can only extend other interfaces--none of them actually `extends Object`, *either explicitly or implicitly*. And yet, all of the `Object` methods are available on every interface. This makes an interface like `List<>` a *subtype* of `Object`--it has all the method signatures that `Object` would have--even though the interface itself does not inherit *implementations* of those methods from the `Object` class.

Answer (score 4):

Inheritance and subtyping are two separate concepts. A type can only inherit from its parent type; therefore inheritance is tied to the *subtype* relationship. However, the reverse does not hold: the subtype does not necessarily inherit anything from its parent. Language rules dictate exactly what is inherited by a subtype.

On the example of Java, private members are not inherited. In Java 8, interfaces can declare static methods, but their subtypes do not inherit those members.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is explicit, subtyping is implicit.

Everything (except the primitive types) is a subtype of object.  If you explicitly use the `extends` keyword, then you are using inheritance.

See also: [Inheritance is not subtyping](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/wcook/papers/InheritanceSubtyping90/CookPOPL90.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

**Subtyping** refers to compatibility of interfaces. A type B is a subtype of A if every function that can be invoked on an object of type A can also be invoked on an object of type B.

**Inheritance** refers to reuse of implementations. A type B inherits from another type A if some functions for B are written in terms of functions of A.

Usually, a subclass can use every method from its superclass, inheritance does not need this

source: [here](http://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/pl2006/lecturenotes/lecture-notes/node28.html)