# In java the inherited class also inherit from class Object?

Tags: java

Is to possible that a superclass that already inherited from Object Class and at same time a subclass that inherited from superclass can also inherited from object class directly ?

Answer (score 1):

No, because that will require [Multiple Inheritence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) - which does not exist in java.

The work-around for multiple inheritence in java is usage of interfaces, and an [interface does not extend object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6056124/572670).

So, in other words - a class can extend only one other class (which in its turn extends Object), but it cannot extend another class.

Answer (score 1):

Java has *multi-level inheritance*.

Say `class X extends class Y`
and then `class Y extends class Z`, then `class X` access `class Object via class Y` (which inturn accesses`class Object via class Z`)