# Are interfaces treated like Objects?

Tags: java

Why is the following code working?

```
interface I { }

class A implements I{
    public String toString(){ return "in a"; }
}

class B extends A{
    public String toString(){ return "in b"; }
}
B b = new B();
A a = b;
I i = a;

System.out.println(i);
System.out.println((B)a);
System.out.println(b);
```

As you can see `i` is a valid parameter to `println` method. Why? By looking at the parameter types accepted by this method, only object seems to be relevant.

[image]

I was searching for an answer and found a few relevant things [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056124/do-interfaces-inherit-from-object-class-in-java):
"**Reference types all inherit from java.lang.Object**. Classes, enums, arrays, and **interfaces are all reference types**."

But also found this: "Do interfaces inherit from Object class in Java?" and the answer: No, they don't. And there is no common "root" interface implicitly inherited by all interfaces either (as in the case with classes) for that matter.(*)

What does this mean? Can someone explain me why is the interface accepted as an argument for the `println` function?

I suppose that the point here is that you cannot pass an object through an interface without having the object itself.

But the question still remains. Why is the compiler accepting an interface as a parameter for this method?

Comment: Interfaces don't inherit `Object`, but any instance implementing any interface inherits `Object`, so has `toString()` method.

Comment: I suppose, when you invoke, System.out.println (....) passing an object to it, compiler would invoke its toString(), thus ideally we are passing a string.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: Not sure what the relevance of `toString` is here...

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Not much relevance. It was added only for the purpose of printing a message and see the method call. `System.out.println` calls the `toString` method on the object.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth just tried: interface variable has all methods of `Object`: `hashCode()`, `equals()` and others.

Comment: The compiler knows that `i` implements the interface - and thus `i` extends `Object`.

Comment: @M.Shaw: Sure.  Where in the JLS is that knowledge encoded, though?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2

Comment: The important distinction that you're not making is that you *don't pass an interface at all*. You pass an *object* that *implements* the interface. When you know that the reason why this works is trivial.

Comment: @AntP: I don't think that's the question.  We all know that the *dynamic* type is correct.  The question is why does the compiler allow us to pass it where there's an apparent mismatch in the *static* type?  This wouldn't work in any other context (e.g. passing an `I` reference to a method that takes `J`, where `B` implements `I` and `J`.)  The answer is given by JB below.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth It's not the question, no, but it is the lack of intuition that has led to the question - the fact that all instances will in some way implement `Object` has already been established but failed to be acknowledged as an explanation, my interpretation of which is that the asker is misinterpreting the semantics of interfaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2) explains it:

> Given a non-generic type declaration C, the direct supertypes of the type C are all of the following:
>
> The direct superclass of C (§8.1.4).
>
> The direct superinterfaces of C (§8.1.5).
>
> The type Object, if C is an interface type with no direct superinterfaces (§9.1.3).

You might ask *why* Object is the supertype of any interface. The reason is that there is no way for an object not to be an instance of a concrete class, and there is no way for this concrete class not to extend Object. Hence, the compiler knows that a reference to an interface type is a reference to an Object.

Comment: Given an `interface` called `Countable`, I am able to pass a reference of type `Countable` that has been initialized to a `null` to the `println` statement. Since `null` is not an object, how does this work?

Comment: @ChetanKinger We're talking about types here, not objects. The type `Object` is always a direct (or indirect) supertype of type `Countable`.

Comment: @biziclop This answer says `Every object is an instance of some concrete class`. I am wondering how this is relevant to the question from the OP and thus my question in the previous comment. That being said, do you mean to say that all references in `java` are `Object`?

Comment: @ChetanKinger it's not directly relevant, because the JLS rule says that every interface type directly or indirectly has Object as its supertype. But then you might ask *why* Object is the supertype of any interface, and the reason is that there is no way for an object not to be an instance of a concrete class, and no way for this concrete class not to extend Object.

Comment: @JBNizet Your edit makes sense now that you add some context to it :)

Answer (score 1):

It is like this. You can not instantiate an interface, so any reference with an interface must point to an object of some class that implements said interface. And that object's superclass must be Object at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Your misunderstanding stems from a conflation. Inheritance and subtyping are separate things.

[The JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4.1) explains the meaning of inheritance:

> An interface `I` *inherits* from its direct superinterfaces all abstract and default methods `m` [...]

When you have something like `class String extends Object {}`, `String` is a *subtype* of `Object` and thereby *inherits members* of the superclass `Object`.

Interfaces, on the other hand, are *subtypes* of `Object` but *do not inherit members* from it. This is what [aioobe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6227003/2891664) is explaining, that interfaces do not inherit.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is not so much accepting an interface as an argument, but rather *a reference to an object* that happens to implement the interface. Consider the following code snippet similar to yours, and the output. You'll see in both cases the output is the Box object. The parameter (or "thing") being passed in both cases to println() is the very same Box object. It's just that in one case it's being referred to as a concrete instantiation of Box, and in the other it's being referenced as an object that implements the A interface.

```
interface A {}

public class Box implements A
{

   public Box()
   {

   }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Box b =new Box();
        A a = b;   //define a reference to an object that implements interface A
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

The output is:

Box@19e0bfd

Box@19e0bfd