# Why are certain Object methods not callable from default methods?

Tags: java, java-8, default-method

When creating a default method in Java 8, certain `Object` methods are not callable from within the default method. For example:

```
interface I {
    default void m() {
        this.toString(); // works.
        this.clone(); // compile-time error, "The method clone() is undefined for the type I"
        this.finalize(); // same error as above.
    }
}
```

It seems that `clone()` and `finalize()` are the only methods from `Object` that are not allowed. Coincidently, these are the only methods of `Object` that are protected, but this question is in particular regard to default methods, as they will be inherited by classes that do extend `java.lang.Object`. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the clone() method protected in java.lang.Object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138769/why-is-the-clone-method-protected-in-java-lang-object)

Comment: @SPrashad I disagree.  That question has nothing to do with why it's not callable in an interface's default method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a coincidence that the `protected` methods from `Object` are not available in a `default` method in an interface.

[Section 9.2 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2) states:

> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a `public abstract` member method `m` with signature `s`, return type `r`, and throws clause `t` corresponding to each `public` instance method `m` with signature `s`, return type `r`, and throws clause `t` declared in `Object`, unless an `abstract` method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible `throws` clause is explicitly declared by the interface.

An interface will not inherit anything from `Object`, but it will implicitly declare all `public` `Object` methods.  This does not include any `protected` methods.  This explains why `clone` and `finalize` can't be called; they are not declared in an interface.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware that interfaces do not inherit from `Object` when they declare `default` method. However, you cannot call a `default` method directly; it must be called on an object whose class directly or indirectly implements the interface. That class will no doubt inherit from `Object`. Thus, it should be safe to allow for this. Interesting design decision.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian Just to clarify, interfaces **never** inherit from `Object`, regardless of whether there is a default method or not. They simply don't. The problem with inheriting from `Object` is that for example the `toString()` method could be overridden by any class implementing `I`, so which implementation should be chosen then? The one inherited by the interface or the one in the class that implements the interface?

Comment: @biziclop If it's the case that interfaces **never** inherit from `Object`, then why is `Object o = i;` where `i` has a compile-time type of an interface legal? Actually, this seems related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056124/do-interfaces-inherit-from-object-class-in-java.

Comment: It is legal due to this specific clause: [`The type Object, if C is an interface type with no direct superinterfaces (§9.1.3).`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2). But this has no relevance as to inheritance, that is controlled by superclass/superinterface relationships. Interface types still don't inherit methods from `Object`. It only implicitly declares the same methods. The difference is rather subtle and seems unnecessary, but it exists.